# compare two data frames and get index from second dataframe for greater value in r programing

Tags: r

I have two data frames which is mentioned below :-

`df1 = data.frame(df1_col = c(0.00002,0.00010,0.00020,0.00100,0.00200))`

`df2 = data.frame(df2_col1=c(0.00001702406727,0.00002002614159,0.00002018336933,0.0000977206871,0.00010785618371,0.00018966630497,0.00020173904639,0.00099759142132,0.00104912583361,0.00194016482197,0.00200732582737)`

now i want to compare each row from df1 with each row of df2 and find out row number(index) of first greatest in df2, from index number i will take data from df2 for that corresponding index number.

**note :- df1 is having less number of rows than df2**

i tired using looping through each row for df1 and df2 and then used `which` function but it didn't work any other simple method is there?

my desired output will be :-

`df3 = data.frame(df1_col1 = c(0.00002,0.00010,0.00020,0.00100,0.00200), df2_col2=c(0.00002002614159,0.00010785618371,0.00020173904639,0.00104912583361,0.00200732582737))`

sorry for any inconvenience . this is my first question . thank you in advance !!!!

******NEW DATA******

df1=data.frame(df1_col1=c(0.00002,
0.00010,
0.00020,
0.00100,
0.00200,
0.00250,
0.00400,
0.00500,
0.01000,
0.02000,
0.03000))

df2=data.frame(df2_col1=c(0.00014940969624,
0.00015836812803,
0.00016803247695,
0.00017844541097,
0.00018966630497,
0.00020173904639,
0.00021473722873,
0.00022871767705,
0.00024376616425,
0.00025995387854,
0.00027740350512,
0.00029622853518,
0.00031659411339,
0.00033867002512,
0.00036270484799,
0.00038895378722,
0.00041774363175,
0.00044938435908,
0.00048425557455,
0.00052270555240,
0.00056516734709,
0.00058803959079,
0.00061213685774,
0.00063753303271,
0.00066436020792,
0.00069271759254,
0.00072278590327,
0.00075471258665,
0.00078871891980,
0.00082495135506,
0.00086370796092,
0.00090520244315,
0.00094974375995,
0.00099759142132,
0.00104912583361,
0.00110468513550,
0.00116471796237,
0.00122961947450,
0.00129997381226,
0.00137633261223,
0.00145941148983,
0.00150367150729,
0.00154993475674,
0.00164886456582,
0.00170177926583,
0.00175721404389,
0.00181530011799,
0.00187625634148,
0.00194016482197,
0.00200732582737,
0.00207790286653,
0.00215216527238,
0.00223029743932,
0.00231263720905,
0.00239942910043,
0.00249104495897,
0.00258772950799,
0.00268995918708,
0.00279808620674,
0.00291260618091,
0.00303393957317,
0.00316270550389,
0.00329945165204,
0.00344491415323,
0.00359970294452,
0.00376478162054,
0.00394100416242,
0.00412946943549,
0.00433124287660,
0.00454769286700,
0.00466181286329,
0.00478015613269,
0.00490287219562,
0.00503023860438,
0.00516231516987,
0.00529948405762,
0.00544190977016,
0.00558989424000,
0.00574363032708,
0.00590348262538,
0.00606970711776,
0.00624269632708,
0.00642267044700,
0.00661012222834,
0.00680537865824,
0.00700890517615,
0.00722105704960,
0.00744238908118,
0.00767333589656,
0.00791450623655,
0.00816629638134,
0.00842946839953,
0.00870457800002,
0.00899236514987,
0.00929347419740,
0.00960877976327,
0.00993906664874,
0.01028531629401,
0.01064836560114,
0.01102939995868,
0.01142946986211,
0.01184984756038,
0.01229174638031,
0.01275666542031,
0.01324605799479,
0.01376164646858,
0.01430505034994,
0.01487834806441,
0.01517680797833,
0.01548355354501,
0.01579883472796,
0.01612301677381,
0.01645629840316,
0.01679913158769,
0.01715180723470,
0.01751473695387,
0.01788823000264,
0.01827276128134,
0.01866870741769,
0.01907658694645,
0.01949670526428,
0.01992970835114,
0.02037603813266,
0.02083628226895,
0.02131092986923,
0.02180065884019,
0.02230604531786,
0.02282781673939,
0.02336654192662,
0.02392307856762,
0.02449812744245,
0.02509254651992,
0.02570710318883,
0.02634276037547,
0.02700040459895,
0.02768108720588,
0.02838568468843,
0.02911543211252,
0.02987138853965,
0.03065480656468,
0.03146687637367,
0.03230902465341,
0.03318262955971,
0.03408928114548,
0.03503049532094,
0.03600813039164,
0.03702399530373,
0.03808014377487,
0.03917864953982,
0.04032188867370,
0.04151227866069,
0.04275252873894,
0.04404534794164,
0.04539391077701,
0.04609007134882,
0.04680142876348))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sort df2

```
> df2=df2[order(df2$df2_col1),,drop=F]
```

using apply to obtain the indices

```
> tmp=apply(df1,1,function(x){which.max(df2$df2_col1>x)})
[1]  2  5  7  9 11
```

using these indices in df2 you get

```
> df2[tmp,]
[1] 2.002614e-05 1.078562e-04 2.017390e-04 1.049126e-03 2.007326e-03
```

Comment: Hi sir! thank you for quick reply. let me try it out . ASAP

Comment: Hi sir. tired your method . but i am getting this ````df1_col1=0.00002,  df2_1=0.00000007686081````  but clearly we can see df1_col1 is greater than df2_1 but we want opposite of that we want df2_1 is greater than df1_col1

Comment: @walle_eva This is what the code `df2$df2_col1>x` is doing, checking which values in df2 are bigger than values in df1, so this should work. It's hard to tell what is going on without seeing what you've done exactly. The results I posted are the same as the ones you posted in your question, so you must have done something different.

Comment: no sir i did same :- csv_file_sorted=csv_file_sorted[order(csv_file_sorted$ep),,drop=F]
index <- apply(percent_devided,1,function(x){which.max(csv_file_sorted$ep>x)})
test12 <- csv_file_sorted$ep[index] 

csv_file_sorted is df2
percent_devided is df1

Comment: @walle_eva The code seems fine. Can you edit your question and add a sample (a couple of rows) of this data which is resulting in this seemingly incorrect answer. On the data you provided in the question this code works, so maybe there is something different with your data.

Comment: definitely!!!!!

Comment: hi please check i edited and added more data !! thank you sir

Comment: @walle_eva Well... there is something wrong with your data, you did not put the elements into a vector `c()`, this results in df2 being a dataframe with as many columns as there are values, which is not correct. Add `c()` around the values in df2 and you will get a dataframe with 1 column and then the code will work.

Comment: no no it was writing mistake in that question so sorry but even if i did that it gives same values :( . actually i am taking data from two different csv files so i just copied from it here as data.frame(c("MY DATA"))

Comment: @walle_eva I don't know what to tell you, my code works for the two data frames that you provided, I checked. So your original data must be in some different format, you need to figure out what is different in your data.

Comment: ohhh okay boss!! but hey thank you and you can do it ask answer because apparently it works !!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way but I bet there are more concise/elegant alternatives.

```
library(dplyr)
tidyr::crossing(df1, df2) %>%
  filter(df1_col < df2_col1) %>%
  group_by(df1_col) %>%
  slice_min(df2_col1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: wow !!! wait let me try it sir ! i will comment u ASAP :)